# Reduce over a single array summing slices

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, splice

I have an array of values

`let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];`

I want to sum specific slices, for example `a.[0] + a.[1]` giving a new array:

`[1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6]`

Is there a recommended way to do this with reduce() or other method? Such as some kind of stepping/range parameter?

Comment: You're going to get answers doing this with `reduce`, but `reduce` is very much **not** the right tool for this job. Why the `reduce` requirement?

Comment: I guess it's not a requirement, I was thinking of numpty with np.add.reduceat method which gives intervals/slices but need this for JS

Comment: Ah, got it. ...

Comment: @JayB will the number of element in the array are always going to be even ? if not than in case of number number of elements what should be desired output, i.e `[1,2,3]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Because I want @T.J. Crowder to be right :)

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

// Loop over all values of the array
const res = a.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
  // Use Math.floor and xi (the index of the value we are treating)
  // to store the values on the returned array at the correct position
  tmp[Math.floor(xi / 2)] = (tmp[Math.floor(xi / 2)] || 0) + x;
  
  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Will also work if the number of element is not pair

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const res = a.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
  tmp[Math.floor(xi / 2)] = (tmp[Math.floor(xi / 2)] || 0) + x;

  return tmp;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

---

Alternative solution :

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const res = [];

do {
  res.push(a.splice(0, 2).reduce((tmp, x) => tmp +x, 0));
} while (a.length);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with `reduce`, but it's not the right tool for the job. Here's how, keying off index and passing an array around:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let result = array.reduce((a, v, i) => {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        // It's an odd entry, so sum it with the
        // previous entry and push to the result array
        a.push(v + array[i - 1]);
    }
    return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

You can squash that into a concise arrow function, at the expense of clarity:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let result = array.reduce((a, v, i) => ((i % 2 === 1 ? a.push(v + array[i - 1]) : 0), a), []);
console.log(result);
```

A simple `for` loop would probably be more appropriate, though:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let result = [];
for (let n = 0; n < array.length; n += 2) {
    result.push(array[n] + array[n + 1]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: *but it's not the right tool for the job...* Why not?

Comment: @TheMaster - My view (and [I'm not alone](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544)) is that most uses of `reduce` are over-complicated compared to alternatives, particularly ones like this where 1) The "accumulator" being passed around never changes, and 2) You're not doing work on every loop. `reduce` is great for things like sums and counts and such, but overcomplicated for most other uses (again, IMHO).

Comment: @TJC Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and taking only the odd indices for a value.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = array.flatMap((v, i, { [i + 1]: w = 0 }) => i % 2 ? [] : v + w);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and quick solution with  [`Array.prototype.reduce`] can look like this:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

const range = 2;

const result = array.reduce((all, item, i) => {

  const idx = Math.floor(i/range);
  if (!all[idx]) all[idx] = 0;
  all[idx] += item;

  return all;

},[]);


console.log(result);
```